# Visual Studio 2012 Install Shield LE Installer Class

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

I have been googling away for a couple hours and can't find what I'm looking for. I'm creating an installer using Visual Studio and InstallShield LE. Those are the only tools I'm currently allowed to use. I have a custom action exe that runs and performs some tasks that require admin privileges. I have already set the Require Administrative Privileges to Yes. 
When the installer runs the user is prompted to elevate permissions but the exe still fails says permission denied. If I have the user Right Click and select run as administrator on the setup.exe then the custom action is able to successfully run. Am I missing something?

Also what exactly does the Files --> installer class do?
and how do you use it.

[image: files]
[image: installer class]

Install shield provided this info

Select this option to ensure that at installation time, the assembly’s Install, Commit, Rollback, and Uninstall methods will be called at the appropriate time.

but how does it do that is there an interface that needs to be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you don't want to go there.  [Installer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) custom actions (InstallUtil) are notoriously fragile and have many disadvantages.   But if you wrote one, this is how you would tell InstallShield to consume it.

If you do need to write managed code custom actions, the much better solution is to use WiX DTF custom actions.  These can be packaged as a merge module and then consumed by IS LE.

Comment: can you expand on why they are notoriously fragile?

Comment: Many reasons. They run out of process and can't use the MSI API it was designed. They tattoo the MSIEXEC process with a CLR version.  The native helper library throws modal error messagebox even when installer is running silent.  The error code 1001 is always displayed regardless of the reason.  They are frequently used to reinvent the wheel (like install a service) when a built in technique exists.  There's some blogs out there that talk about all this.